# new mail counter javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am having some major problems with a javascript app I'm working on.  I want my window to open to a closed envelope and then after five seconds to change to an open envelope with a little 1 counter in the corner of it.  I want the counter to continue to move up every five seconds unless the envelope is clicked.  If clicked I want the count to start over.  So far I have only gotten my closed envelope showing up.  I'm new and have no idea what I am doing wrong so any help would be awesome!
My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mail.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id"closed" src="closed.png" onclick="resetTimer()">
        <span id="counter"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var counter = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(
        function(){         
            counter++; 
            document.getElementById("demo").firstChild.nodeValue = counter;
        }, 
        5000
    );              

    function openEnvelope(){
         var img = document.getElementById("picture");
         if (counter > 1){
             img.src = "open.png"
         }
    }
    open = setTimeout("open()", 1000);

    function resetTimer(){
         clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment your counter and set the counter span to have that value :

```
        var counter = 0;
        //Create your timer (setTimeout will only run once, setInterval will start again once run.
        //1000 = 1 second
        var timer = setInterval(openEnvelope, 1000);

        function openEnvelope() {
            var img = document.getElementById("picture");
            var counterSpan = document.getElementById("counter");
            if (counter > 1) {
                img.src = "open.png"
                counterSpan.innerHTML = counter;
            }
            //Add 1 to Counter
            counter++;
        }

        function resetTimer() {
            clearInterval(timer);
            counter = 0;
        }
```

This will run your `openEnvelope` function every second, and if the counter value is more than `1` it will set the Img Source to be `open.png` and the `counter` span to have the counters value. On the click of the Envelope it will clear the timer and reset the counter.

And your HTML will become :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="mail.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id"picture" src="closed.png" onclick="resetTimer()">
        <span id="counter"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzEfL/) for your problem, try creating a blank page and copying the HTML straight into the `<body>` tag and the Javascript into `<script></script>` tags in the `<head>` of your page.

Comment: Another problem is this part: `var img = document.getElementById("picture");`. There is no element with the id `picture`.

Comment: Ah thanks, didn't notice that. I've modified his html and added it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and it makes sense but I'm still just getting the closed envelope with no counter...

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console ([Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console), [FireFox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console), [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589530(v=vs.85).aspx))? If so what are they? If not then have you tried placing your code inside the `<script></script` tags on your page?

Comment: When I used Firebug in Firefox with my external js I received the error "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
 

document.getElementById("demo").firstChild.nodeValue = counter;},"

Comment: When I added my script on my page I received that img.src = "open.png" was null

Comment: Have you tried placing **only** the code I have suggested into `<script></script` tags on your page? It seems that it might be your old code creating the errors. And that code should not be needed with the code I have suggested.

Comment: I did take your suggestion and added the script tags into my html but still nothing.

Comment: I have added a JSFiddle to my answer, it shows a working solution (although the image can't be found).